# nginx rewrite leads to redirect loop

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

I'm using nginx with a reverse proxy to my gunicorn django server at local to run my django app.

I am trying to force ssl from any http request, as the site is only intended https access. The app will ONLY listen to port 8888, (80 and 443 taken), so the site should only be accessible when specified the 8888 port.

I tried to rewrite with this `rewrite ^ https://domain.net:8888$request_uri? permanent;` in the server block and location block. Not only does it not redirect http requests to the same url, it also causes a redirect loop when there is a https request.

```
server {
    listen 8888;
    server_name sy-system.net;
    rewrite ^ https://domain.net:8888$request_uri? permanent;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/domain.key;

    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /media/ {
        root /path/to/root;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/root;
    }

    location / {
        #rewrite ^ https://sy-system.net:8888$request_uri? permanent;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8881/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
   }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unconditionally redirecting from domain.net:8888 to domain.net:8888.  An infinite redirect loop is the only possible result.

In any case, what you are attempting to do isn't possible. Nginx is talking SSL, your browser is not, so no data will be transferred between them (which is why you don't get the redirect loop when connecting with plain HTTP).  When they do talk (via SSL) your redirect loop takes over.